# Who is Kirszbraun?

Tags: soft-question, ho.history-overview

[Kirszbraun's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirszbraun_theorem) is one of my favorite theorems in mathematics.

I always wanted to know something about Kirszbraun, or at least to see his picture.
Do you have any information about him?
(I know only trivial things, like where he was publishing and that he was working in Warsaw.)

**Postscript.** Thanks to Lukasz Grabowski, I fould the following entry about Kirszbraun in Polish Biographical Dictionary.

[image]

**Plus,** some scanned documents related to Kirszbraun can be requested from [USHMM](https://www.ushmm.org/online/hsv/person_view.php?PersonId=6965617); in particular, there is his picture.

[image]

Comment: Curious enough - I wanted to ask a similar question about Dobinski (Dobinski's formula) but I had my doubts whether it's appropriate for MO or not :)

Comment: Any chance you could comment on what you use Kirszbraun's theorem for?

Comment: @Deane, love can not be explained, BUT, assume you have a closed curve in the plane and you map it to the plane on such a way that all distances decrease. Try to prove that the area bounded by this curve decrease without Kirszbraun...

Comment: @AntonPetrunin The link "this entry" in your post does not work :(

Comment: The note was written by  a famous mathematician Marczewski. As a mathematician is known under two different names Marczewski and Szpilrajn. From Wikipedia:  He was born Szpilrajn but changed his name [to Marczewski] while hiding from Nazi persecution.

Comment: Since the biography is so short, perhaps someone knowledgeable in Polish could add an English translation as an answer?

Comment: @j.c.read Wikipedia --- everything is there and it seems that nothing else is known.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apparently he has an entry written by [Edward Marczewski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Marczewski) in the [polish biographical dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_Biographical_Dictionary) , according to [the official site of the publisher](http://www.psb.pan.krakow.pl/). Somewhat suprisingly there seem to be no library which has this dictionary where I live so I can't help you any further.

Best of luck! I know the feeling - I once wanted to learn anything about Wegge-Olsen who wrote [a nice book on K-theory](https://books.google.com/books?id=EVOjQgAACAAJ&dq=k+theory&hl=en&ei=MPzJTL6mIoPMswbHsfWfDg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CD4Q6AEwBDhG). I haven't found anything in internet, but in the end I asked Paul Baum accidentally and he told me a bit about him.

Comment: Oh, Edward Marczewski, the one who proved that HausDim $\ge$ TopDim :) 
I will find this book; it is just a technical problem.

Comment: "we want to thank L. Grabowski for bringing to our 
attention the entry about Kirszbraun in the Polish
Biographical Dictionary."

http://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.5636.pdf

Comment: @Anton, cheers :-)

Comment: I took a class in K-Theory from Niels Erik when he was visiting Berkeley in the early 90s. Very interesting guy. As I recall, besides being a mathematician he was also a highly accomplished organist.  Google locates a ["Niels Erik Wegge"](https://udvandrerne.dk/new-zealand/job/niels-erik-wegge/) who seems to be the same person. Apparently he now lives in New Zealand.

Answer (score 14):

[This Banach biography web page in Polish](http://kielich.amu.edu.pl/Stefan_Banach/zyciorys.html) says that Kirszbraun was born in 1903 or 1904 and died in 1942 (he is listed there among other Polish mathematicians who died in the course of WW II). Further googling revealed that his full name was Mojżesz David Kirszbraun. According to the [Zentralblatt Math.](http://www.zentralblatt-math.org/zmath/en/advanced/) database, he wrote just one paper in German (just as Mark mentioned in the comments):

Kirszbraun, M.D.
[Über die zusammenziehenden und Lipschitzschen Transformationen](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm22/fm22112.pdf). (German)
Fundam. Math. 22, 77-108 (1934).

Here is the [link](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A60.0532.03&format=complete) to the review of this paper by Freudental.

Perhaps some Polish colleague(s) could provide further details.

Comment: Maybe he was Jewish?

Comment: @Yuval: The name suggests he was. Kirszbraun sounds German but spelled Polish way (with sz for sch) +  Mojżesz=Moses.

Comment: @Anton, once you get a bit more information, maybe you could edit the Wikipedia page.

Comment: @Alex: I made a stub http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moj%C5%BCesz_David_Kirszbraun but so far there is almost nothing to say

Comment: @Anton: It looks like he wrote just one paper. At least only one published in Fundamenta Mathematicae: http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm22/fm22112.pdf . The first after war issue of Fundamenta has a list of some Polish mathematicians that died during the war, but does not list Kirszbraun: http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm33/fm3311.pdf . Do you know any other papers written by Kirszbraun? 

Comment: I saw few papers of Kirszbraun. (MathSciNet/Zentralblatt do not list old papers...) 

Comment: @Anton: In which journals? Zentralblatt lists only one paper. I checked all Fundamenta issues from the very beginning. These are available online. 

Comment: Maybe I am wrong (my memory plays bad games with me sometime). On the other hand Zentralblatt does not list years <1933 or so (and MathSciNet is even worse).

Answer (score 9):

It is very, VERY likely that Kirszbraun published only one paper. Namely, if you read carefully that short entry in Polish (written by E.Marczewski = Szpilrajn), you'll notice that in the penultimate sentence it says that upon completing his studies he got a job as an **actuary** ("aktuariusz", the person who calculates insurance costs) in an insurance company named "Przyszlosc"; therefore, it is quite reasonable to assume that he didn't continue any form of a(n academic) career as a research mathematician. On the other hand, a footnote an the title page of its Fundamenta paper clearly indicates that the paper is an abridged and improved version of his "Magister" (= Master) thesis, defended back in 1930 and prepared in the preceding 4-year period. So, it is rather safe to jump to the conclusion that *Über die zusammenziehenden und Lipschitzschen Transformationen* is his only publication, and that he didn't pursued any further mathematical research.